# Reading into an arrary from file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to read from file into an array. I know I need to read until I hit a space `(' ')` and then when I hit the end of the line `('\n')` skip to the next line. I am not sure how to do this. I tried reading until `(array != ' ')` but this does not seem to work. Any tips?

**Input:**

SALESMAN MONTH PROGRAM WRITE

SEE THE BLUE SKY

CAT THROUGH A RAN

THE TOP TUMBLED TO

WHENEVER WATER WAS WHITE

CHARLES CHECK CHEERS CHEAP

A BLUE CLEAR SKY

PAIR PAUL PETER PHILLIP

ADELE CARY DAVID ELAINE

TABLE CHAIR BED DOG

Comment: Hi, you mention that you have some code. Would you show it to us?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so people can help you more and you can get proper answers.

Comment: `while (!ins.eof())
 { 
  str1 = 'a';
  while (str1 != ' ')
  {
   ins >> str1;
  }
  
 
 }`

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58928381/edit) your code into your question rather than posting it as a comment

Comment: Change your perspective: first read an entire line, then divide that line. Read about `std::istringstream` and `std::getline` in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the proper C++ way of reading the file. This code reads the desired file line by line and stores the words into a vector. You can use this as a reference in your own application.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;

    std::ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("text.txt");
    if (!inFile) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::string input;

    /* read file line by line */
    while(std::getline(inFile, input)) {
        std::stringstream ss{input};
        std::string word;

        /* read words separated by space*/
        while (ss >> word) {
            words.push_back(word);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Printing words in file" << std::endl;

    for(auto &word : words) {
        std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

maybe you need just

```
   std::ifstream file(filename);
   char ch;
   while (!file.eof())
   {
      file >> ch;
      if (ch == ' ')
      {
          // do something
      }
   }
```

Comment: Required reading: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)